# Is there a way to add route to Rails by command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am a beginner in ruby on rails. I found it quite inconvenience to add route to route.rb manually every time I add a new action or page to controller or the project. So I want to know if there is a way using command line rather than editing the route.rb file?

Comment: You mean similar to a Rails generator for model or migrations? If so, then the answer is No.

Comment: Yes,just like when we use "rails generate controller ctrler act" it will generate a controller-ctrler and an action-act and configure the routes.rb file for us automatically. What I want is a similar way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding routes to the routes.rb file from the terminal can be easily achieved with **sed**.

*Install sed using the following command (Ubuntu):*

```
sudo apt get install sed
```

Assuming you are in the root directory of your app, here is the command to add the routes:-

```
sed -i '23iresources :people' config/routes.rb
```

This is what it does:

1. File to add text to is config/routes.rb
2. Line number to insert text to is 23
3. -i is the insert flag: the text will be inserted
4. **resources :people** is what gets added

Now, the route *resources :people* will be inserted on line 23 in *config/routes.rb* file in your Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a commandline way to update routes, but you might consider using wildcards instead, that way a single line in your routes file can allow you to access many pages on your site:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. That's a good alternative way to do that, according to this article, what comes to my mind is to add all the pages under one controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you do rails generate -h

```
rails generate -h                                                                                                                                                  
Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  job
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  task
```

As you can see there is no generator for routes by default. This is one of the points where rails runs out of its Magic. Of course you can write your generator [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).

But I would recommend, be ready to write code when there isn't a quick default way. Once you become a pro you will quite often see rails magic falling short of the solution your are trying to implement.